# Drawn shape using path creating issue when added in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-canvas

I have created custom view and trying to draw a shape in on draw. Shape is shown in the attachment in CYAN color. But when I add that custom view in recycler view after scrolling its original width and overlapping view. If I try to use line it won't create any prob but only path is creating the problem. Please suggest a way to achieve the shape I want to use.

Code I used to draw shape in `onDraw()` method

```
            int totalWidth=xMargin+width;
            int totalHeight=yMargin+height;
            //draw required share here
            path.moveTo(totalWidth,yMargin);
            path.lineTo(totalWidth,yMargin);
            path.lineTo(totalWidth-offset,yMargin+offset);
            path.lineTo(totalWidth-offset,totalHeight-offset);
            path.lineTo(totalWidth-2*offset,totalHeight);
            path.lineTo(xMargin,totalHeight);
            path.lineTo(xMargin,yMargin+offset);
            path.lineTo(xMargin+offset,yMargin);

            canvas.drawPath(path, pathPaint);
```

[image]

You can see when I scroll, my drawing shape is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As path was not resetting hence it was drawing overlapping drawing portions.
by adding
`path.reset();`
before `path.moveTo(totalWidth,yMargin);`  my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information provided, I can assume that your shapes (chat bubbles) are not being evaluated right by the RecyclerView since it may not know the shape's type/size for each item of the list, which causes your list to collide some items.
With this in mind, I can say that I had a similar problem and solved using these lines:

```
    // Invalidate data
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Hard reset of the list
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

With the lines above we reset the adapter to invalidate the data set forcing the recycler to discard all item views and recreate new ones (Now with the correct views for each item).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Problem solved after adding path.reset(). I have posted ans for future reference. Thanks.